# Cannot access androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.ViewHolder

Tags: java, android

I am using external library that makes SDSimpleRecyclerAdapter and once i build this happiens
error: cannot access RecyclerView
public class GameBetCoinsOptionAdapter extends SDSimpleRecyclerAdapter
^
class file for androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView not found

I tried to add dependancy for androidx.... recycleView but it is the same